# Dividing NumberFormatter .currency to convert a price into quarterly price

Tags: swift, currency, nsnumberformatter

I have a NumberFormatter() with numberStyle as .currency. I am trying to convert this to a quarterly price by dividing it by 4.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = product.priceLocale // product is a SKProduct object.
```

Attempting to divide by 4:

```
let quarter = NSDecimalNumber(value: 4)
let quarterly = formatter.string(from: product.price / quarter)
```

gives the error:

> 'NSDecimalNumber' is not implicitly convertible to 'Decimal'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

I also tried:

```
let quarterly = formatter.string(from: (product.price as Decimal) / quarter)
```

which gives the error:

> Expression type 'NSDecimalNumber' is ambiguous without more context

How can I divide NumberFormatter.currency by 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `product` is an `SKProduct` then `price` is an `NSDecimalNumber`. That class provides the `dividing` method.

```
let quarterly = formatter.string(from: product.price.dividing(by: quarter))
```

Comment: Worked great. Much cleaner than the approach I was taking. Thank you @rmaddy for your help.